# In which case $\mathbb E[X]=\sum _ix_i P[x_i]$ can be $0$ when all $x$'s are not zero ($0$)?

Tags: probability, self-study, references, expected-value, sufficient-statistics

Say $X$ is a random variable and $x$'s are realizations of $X$ .

Say , $\mathbb E[X]=\sum _ix_i P[x_i]=0$ . But I do not understand in which case $\mathbb E[X]=\sum _ix_i P[x_i]$  can be $0$ when all $x$'s are not zero ($0$) ?

Comment: Based on this question and [this other one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/148663/6633), there seems to be a lot of confusion in your mind about samples, realizations, means, etc. The expectation of a discrete random variable taking on values $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ with probabilities $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ is _defined_ to be $$E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^n x_ip_i.\tag{1}$$ All the $p_i$ are _positive. Thus the question seems to be "How can $E[X]$ equal $0$ for some random variables even though all the $x_i$ are _nonzero?_ The answer is that $E[X]=0$ can occur only when $n=1$ and $x_1=0$ or when some of the $x_i$ ..

Comment: ... (continued) have _negative_ value and the sum of the negative terms $x_ip_i$ in $(1)$ cancels out the sum of the positive terms $x_jp_j$ as in Stephan Kolassa's or silverfish's answer.

Comment: An alternative puzzlement might be "How can $E[X]$ equal $0$ even though all the $x_i$ are nonzero and so $X$ itself cannot have value $0$ at all? Why should we _expect_ the value of $X$ to be $0$ when we already _know_ that $X$ cannot equal $0$?"  To this, the response must be (as in silverfish's answer) that $E[X]$ is the _center of mass_, and it is not necessary that there be mass at the center of mass. For example, the center of mass of a doughnut is in the hole where there is no doughnut mass at all! (it is over in the a box on the next rack labeled "doughnut holes")

Comment: @Dilip That's an insightful comment on a plausible source of confusion. I have placed such an example in my answer!

Answer (score 10):

How about

$$ x_1 = 1, P(x_1)=\frac{1}{2}, \qquad x_2 = -1, P(x_2)=\frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: For the curious, this is known as the [Rademacher distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution).

Comment: @silverfish And there are those who will say that $X=2B-1$ where $B \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\frac 12)$, but I prefer to write $X=(-1)^B$ instead. (I use this a lot in professional work in digital communications where $0$'s and $1$'s are mapped to $\{-1,+1\}$ for transmission purposes).

Answer (score 7):

At least one of the $x_i$ in the support of $X$ must be negative for the mean to be zero, so long as there is non-zero probability of a positive $x_i$ occurring. Otherwise each $x_i P(X=x_i) \geq 0$, and there is at least one $i$ for which $x_i P(X=x_i) > 0$, so $\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i P(X=x_i) > 0$.

[By analogy to mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28physics%29), the mean is the "first moment" of the distribution. Imagine a light see-saw with weights corresponding to the probability masses, $P(X=x_i)$, each placed at a position $x_i$ from the zero point on the line. A negative $x_i$ would be on the left of the zero point, a positive $x_i$ on the right. If the mean is zero, that is saying the centre of mass of all these probability masses is at the zero point — so the see-saw would be perfectly balanced if we placed the pivot there.

[image: Probability mass function on a see saw and moments about a pivot representing the mean]

In the example above, I put:

$\Pr(X=x) =  
   \begin{cases}
    2/10  & \text{if } x = -3 \\
    3/10 &\text{if } x = 0 \\
    4/10  & \text{if } x = 1 \\
    1/10  & \text{if } x = 2 \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$

Can you see, physically, why the see-saw will not turn about the pivot, because its clockwise and anticlockwise moments about zero are balanced? Can you use $\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_i x_i P(X=x_i)$ to show why $\mathbb{E}(X)=0$? Of course, there are very many different distributions I could have chosen. Any distribution which is symmetric about zero, such as the [Rademacher distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution) in Stephan Kolassa's answer, or the famous standard normal distribution, as an example of a continuous variable, would have worked too. But this example shows some asymmetric distributions also work.

If you only allowed a probability mass at zero, and at least one probability mass on the right hand side (corresponding to a positive $x_i$), but disallowed any masses on the left hand side (negative $x_i$) then there would be a moment about zero turning it clockwise. So we could not balance the see-saw with a pivot at zero, hence zero cannot be the mean. Intuitively this is why, for a zero mean, we need to balance out the positive $x_i$ on the right with at least one negative $x_i$ on the left which can give us the counterbalancing anti-clockwise moment.

Consider the random variable with the following probability mass function. It would not balance about zero (it would tip clockwise if you pivoted it there), but would balance about a pivot at $\mathbb{E}(X)=2$. Note that *taking moments about zero finds the first (raw) moment*, which by definition is equal to the mean. You can verify that, taking clockwise as positive, the total moment about zero here is indeed $2$. On the other hand, *taking moments about the mean finds the first [central moment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_moment)*. Now as the distribution balanced about the mean, the total moment is zero: this is a general result, and the first central moment, if it exists, is always zero. (The *second* central moment, where we square the distance from the mean before summing, is rather more interesting: it is the [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) of the distribution.)

\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
\hline
\Pr(X=x) & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{2}{7} & \frac{4}{7}\\
\hline
\end{array}

[image: Distribution with non-zero mean]

We could transform this distribution to have zero mean by moving the probability masses around. One simple way is to follow Glen_b's suggestion and define $Y=X - \mu_X$. The new mean is $\mathbb{E}(Y)=\mathbb{E}(X - \mu_X) = \mathbb{E}(X) - \mathbb{E}(\mu_X) = \mu_X - \mu_X = 0$ (using [linearity of expectations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity), and that the [expectation of a constant is the constant itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Constants)). In our case $Y=X-2$: we translate the masses on the see-saw left by two units. After the translation, we have probability masses in both positive and negative positions, so the clockwise and anticlockwise moments about zero can cancel each other out. Note how the centre of mass can be at zero, even with no mass placed there!

\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
y & -2 & -1 & 1 \\
\hline
\Pr(Y=y) & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{2}{7} & \frac{4}{7}\\
\hline
\end{array}

[image: Transformed distribution with zero mean]

**R code for see-saw plots (pivots added in MS Paint)**

```
seesawPlot <- function(values, masses, xlimits=c(-max(abs(values)), max(abs(values)))) {
    x <- rep(values, times=masses)
    y <- unlist(lapply(masses, function(i){1:i}))
    plot(x, y, ylim=c(0,50), xlim=xlimits, pch=19, col="blue",
        yaxt="n", yaxs="i", frame=F, xlab="", ylab="")
}

values <- c(-3, 0, 1, 2); masses <- c(2, 3, 4, 1)
seesawPlot(values, masses)

values <- c(0, 1, 3); masses <- c(1, 2, 4)
seesawPlot(values, masses)

values <- values - 2
seesawPlot(values, masses, xlimits=c(-3,3))
```

Answer (score 5):

> But I do not understand in which case $E[X]=∑_ix_iP[x_i]$ can be $0$ when all $x$'s are not zero ($0$)

You can construct any number of such distributions.

e.g. let $Y\sim F_Y$ for some distribution function $F_Y$ with mean $\mu$, in which not all values lie at the mean -- then some will lie above it and some will lie below it.

Let $X=Y-\mu$. Then $E(X)=0$.

($\text{Var}(X)$ and indeed all central moments will be unaffected by the shift.)

[image]

The mass that was below the mean will now lie below 0, and the mass above it will lie above zero.

---

After pondering the question more closely, I wonder if the question here:

> $E[X]=∑_ix_iP[x_i]$ can be $0$ when all $x$'s are not zero ($0$)

is actually "how can the expectation be a value that's not observable"? The answer to that follows directly from the definition of expectation. It's analogous to asking "how can the center of mass of the [Pluto-Charon system lie outside either body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charon_%28moon%29)?" (The same is true of the earth-moon system.)

The center of mass can be in a place where there's *no mass at all.* It is no more astonishing for probability mass (or probability density) than it is for physical mass.

Handwaving aside, the answer eventually falls back to "because it's defined that way".

If I take a fair six-sided die, the average outcome is 3.5 even though you can never observe it in a single outcome (and most *unfair* (loaded) six-sided dice also have unobservable means). There's nothing magical about it - the long term average from many tosses can be a value you can't see in a single toss. Indeed, it's acceptable for it to be a value you can't observe in any finite number of tosses (the expectation can be irrational).

Comment: Could you explain how this answers the question asked? Perhaps a little more explanation, suggesting to rank beginners that $E[X]=0$ and var$(X) = \sigma^2 > 0$ together imply that $P\{X < 0\} > 0$, and so some of the $x_i$ might be negative, is needed?

Comment: @Dilip I upvoted this answer because it provides a general, full, succinct, and revealing response by pointing out that *any* distribution can easily be converted into one with a zero expectation simply by subtracting a constant from all values. (Moreover, since the process is reversible, this shows that *all* zero-expectation distributions arise in this way and that all zero-expectation distributions with support bounded below arise in this fashion from *non-negative* distributions.) The references to variances are irrelevant and perhaps a little distracting, but not wrong.

Comment: @whuber Yes, any distribution (with finite mean) can be converted to a distribution with zero mean. But this is _irrelevant_ to the issue because what is needed is the understanding that (except in the case of degenerate random variables that have value $\mu$ a.s.) there is _nonzero_ probability mass to the left of the mean as well as to the right of the mean. As I suggested, to anyone above rank beginner status, this might well be trivially obvious and thus not worthy of mention. I continue to insist that Glen's answer is incomplete (though succinct) and not "a general, full, ... revealing"

Comment: What about distributions which are parametrized not by $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$? For example Cauchy distribution has mean undefined.

Comment: @xeon if the mean is undefined, then no location shift will make it defined.

Comment: @whuber the reference to variance (which may be distracting) was to point out that the variance is unaffected by the shift. I can eliminate that without harm if you think it would improve the answer.

Comment: @Dilip I think that Glen's edits might well have addressed your concerns.